# Displaying a div when button is clicked Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

My goal is to display a div with a successfull message when the Save button is clicked.
Unfortunately, all I managed to do is display this message everytime the page is loaded..

Here is my code :

```
<div id="fadeDiv">
    <p>Content saved !</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fadeDiv').fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function () { $('#fadeDiv').fadeOut(1000); }, 1000);
});
```

I tried to do

```
$('#saveBtn").click(...);
```

but when I click on the button, the page is reload even if I don't have a Response.Redirect() so my div is not displayed.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show us the html of your saveBtn? And also `$('#saveBtn").click(...)` dosnt work. It should be like this: `$('#saveBtn").on('click',[function])`

Comment: is your save button type = "submit" ? if so you should preventDefault it

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt The `.click()` method works fine on static content. It would help to see the HTML though, especially if the `button` is within a `form`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Oh i did not know this. Thanks for pointing it out :D

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt here is the html for my button : 
`<asp:Button ID="btnEnregistre" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success-reverse" Text="Enregistrer" OnClick="btnEnregistre_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="form" />`

Comment: Your button has a OnClick attribute set. This triggers a post back to the server every time you click on it (Reloads the site). Do you really need to trigger a server side event on this button click?

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt i placed my button in an UpdatePanel so the page is not reloaded after a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your fast answers !
I manage to do it !

So I put my button in an asp UpdatePanel to avoid the fact that when it was clicked, the page was reloaded. After that I add a RegisterStartupScript in the C# function called when the button was clicked. Finally, the RegisterStartupScript is simply calling the Javascript function that manage the display of my message.

Here is the code :

**HTML**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="saveBtn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="saveBtn_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div id="fadeDiv" style="display: none">
    <p id="saveMsg">Content saved</p>
</div>
```

**C#**

```
protected void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "call", "displaySaveMsg();", true);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function displaySaveMsg() {
    $('#fadeDiv').fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function () { $('#fadeDiv').fadeOut(1000); }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution hides the button at the beginning.

```js
$("#saveBtn").click(function () {
    $('#fadeDiv').fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function () { $('#fadeDiv').fadeOut(1000); }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div id="fadeDiv" style="display:none">
    <p>Content saved !</p>
</div>

<button id="saveBtn">
Save!
</button>
```

Comment: This is assuming that the button is not in a `form` - which is likely given that the OP states clicking the button causes the page to transfer/reload

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still does not work for me... I tried to put a simple alert() in it but nothing is displayed.
`$('#btnEnregistre').click(function () {
alert('ALERT');
});`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link and try with your own.

[Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein)

and let me know if you want any assist.

Answer (score 0):

**There is the solution to your problem**
1.Here is our html

```
    <div id="fadeDiv">
      <p>Content saved !</p>
    </div>
   <button id="saveBtn">Show</button>
```

2.Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#fadeDiv").hide();
      $("#saveBtn").click(function(){
        $("#fadeDiv").show();
      });
    });
```

Explanation of problem solution.
1.html structure is same as yours,solution is in there jquery code.

A.  This line $("#fadeDiv").hide(); hides the div when we arrive first time on our page.

B. And this code will run when we click the save button
$("#saveBtn").click(function(){

});.

C.the last thing ,this line $("#fadeDiv").show(); will show the hidden div.

Answer (score 0):

To re-create what you'd like to do, I created an HTML with a hidden div that has the message to be displayed within a red bordered div on successful save. Note that the button is outside the div.

Secondly, I created a simple JavaScript function that triggers the display of the div and hides the save button.

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
    //show div when button is clicked               
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
    //hide save button after click
    document.getElementById("saveButton").style.display = "none";
                                    
    }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none; border-style: solid; border-width:thick; border-color:red;">
 <p> Hey..!! <br><br>Your Content saved!! :)</p>
</div>
<button onclick="ShowHideDiv()" id = "saveButton">Save Button</button>
```

I hope it's what you're trying to achieve.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will open and close as per need

```js
$("#saveBtn").click(function(){
        $("#fadeDiv").toggle(200);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will open and close as per need

```js
$("#saveBtn").click(function(){
        $("#fadeDiv").toggle(200);
      });
```

```js
This will open and close as per need

$("#saveBtn").click(function(){
        $("#fadeDiv").toggle(200);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fadeDiv" style="display:none">
<p>Content saved !</p>
</div>
```